# How to Build Docker image of an AngularApp so it use ClusterIP service ok k8s deployment toconnect WebAPI?

Tags: angular, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a demo app frontend built in Anguler; the backend is dotnet core. I make a backend docker image and this is my docker file.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["webApi/webApi.csproj", "webApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "webApi/webApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/webApi"
RUN dotnet build "webApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "webApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webApi.dll"]
```

I successfully deploy it on my k8s cluster and created a CLusterIP service.

```
backend-service.managerappstack:5000
```

Now I used this ClusterIP service in my angular APP as follows and build a docker image for the front end.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Project } from './projectModel';

@Injectable({
  provided: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  push(arg0: {
  
    severity: string; summary: string; detail: string;
  }) {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
  readonly APIUrl="http://backend-service.managerappstack:5000/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ToList():Observable<any[]>{
      return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/Project');
  }
  getproject(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/project');
  }
  addProject(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/project',val);
  }
  updateProject(val:any){
    return this.http.put(this.APIUrl+'/project',val);
  }
  deleteProject(val:any){
    return this.http.delete(this.APIUrl+'/project/'+val);
  }

  getEmployee(): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl+'/Employee');
  }
  addEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.post(this.APIUrl+'/Employee',val);
  }
  updateEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.put(this.APIUrl+'/Employee',val);
  }
  deleteEmployee(val:any){
    return this.http.delete(this.APIUrl+'/Employee/',val);
  }
```

After deploying this image on k8s I expose my front-end as a load balancer. I can see the frontend app content but I can't see any data from web API like projects employees etc.

**What did I test:**
If I convert the web API into a load balancer then I can see data in Swagger.
Also if I build an image of the front end with the load balancer IP of Webapi I can see data.

**Conclusion:**
It Seems like the CLusterIP server is not successfully communicating with the front end. I am using HTTP to test both the front end and back end.

**What Do I want:**
Can you please help me to make images correctly for my CLusterIP? So the backend should serve data to the frontend Angular APP? Both Deployments are in the same namespaces.
I have very little Exprinces in Angular and dotnet core. It will be a great help if you support me.

Comment: did you try the internally with from another pod ? and clusterip working or not. what actual error are you seeing ?

Comment: I dont see any error. In inspect network tab I see this    Request URL:
http://backend-service.managerappstack:5000/api/project
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin           It seems like its hitting to correct service.

Comment: Your angular app won't be able to communicate with backend pods via `ClusterIP` Service because ClusterIPs only work within tjhe k8s cluster. Browser only understands publicly accessible URL as it executes all the compiled HTML, CSS & JS files locally. **You will to expose your backend through `Ingress` resource or `LoadBalancer` type Service and use it in your Frontend Docker image**.

Comment: I used the ingress but its a security risk if someone simply uses my ingress IP/Domain/api it will return the data. This is not what anyone wants. I only want to expose the front end.